# Could you translate this Hebrew poetry to English?

Tags: hebrew, rabbis, song-poetry

Shalom aleichem,

Could you translate this Hebrew poetry to English?
I listened to this poetry (but in form of a song) in Idan Raichel's first album.
It is of R. Shlomo Shabezi.

Im Tepetzchah (If Thou Wisheth)

~~~~~

לוחות שניים הם -  Luchot sh'naim hem

ביושר נכתבו - beyosher nichtevu

בם דיברות עשר - bam dibrot asar

בעדות נחקרו - be'edut nech'keru

~~~~~

שמעו לאנוכי - Shme'u le'anochi

ולא יהיה לך - ve'lo yihyeh lecha

מפי גבורה הם - mefi g'vurah hem

ותורה שמרו - vetorah shimru

~~~~~

ברוך אשר זיכה - Baruch asher zichah

עדתו לחזות - edato lechazot

תורה תמימה בה - torah t'mimah bah

נפשות כשרו - nafshot k'sheru.

~~~~~

זכרה אדון הכל - Zichra adon hakol

לחן תורתך - lechen toratcha

קבץ פזורנו - kavatz p'zorenu

אשר נתפזרו - asher nitp'zru

Todah rabbah.

Comment: Do you all think it is related to Judaism because it is religious poetry authored by a rabbi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very roughly:

```
The tablets are two,
written earnestly,
in them commandments ten,
examined as testimony.

[The Jews] heard [the 1st commandment] "I am ..."
and [the 2nd] "you shall not have ..."
from the Almighty,
and the laws [i.e. the remaining 611 commandments] they kept

Bless the One who let
His congregation experience
the perfect Torah within it
their souls were perfected

Remember, Master of all,
to the grace of your Torah,
gather our scattered people
who have been cast all over.
```

There are 613 commandments in the Torah, but the letters of the word "Torah" add up to 611; the Talmud says the first two commandments at Sinai were heard directly from G-d; everything else was conveyed through Moses. The poet is referencing that above.